# sql - return one row from each group

Tags: sql, grouping

Considering the tables below, what is the best way to only return the team membership and its related player, but only one player from each team? The important part to note is that selection needs to be based on a given set of player ids. That is the starting point.

Using the example below I would have the player ids: 1,2,3 (among others) and what I need to end up with is the unique memberships from a list of user ids(1,2,3 in this case). I would want to end up with team_memberships with id 1 & 2

Thanks!

```
player
id | name
1  | bob
2  | joe
3  | tom

team_memberships
id | team_id | player_id
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 2       | 2
3  | 1       | 3

team
id | name
1  | jets
2  | kings
```

Comment: can you show us an example result set?

Comment: what should be the criteria for deciding which one player is to be selected for each team? The one with the lowest ID? In your sample data, team_id #1 has two players, Bob and Tom. Which one should be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean

`Select team_id, Min(player_id)

    From team_Memberships

    Where player_id In (1,2,3)

     Group By team_id`

If the player selected needs to be based on some other attribute in the players table, then:

```
Select team_id, 
   (Select Min(player_id) -- in case more than one player satisfies criterion
    From players 
    where playerId = m.Player_Id
       And [Some other ctiterion]) playerId
From team_Memberships m
Where player_id In (1,2,3)  
Group By team_id
```

Comment: please see my comment on the original question. This answer certainly seems spot on if it's the lowest player ID that should be returned for each team!

Comment: thanks! What about the situation where the player selected needs to be based on a field in the players table?

Comment: ok, so this is great, thanks! What about the best way to join on the players table to return the players first_name and keeping it only one player per team?

Comment: To clarify, this is postgresql which seems to treat the following differently:

SELECT team_id, p.name, Min(player_id)
FROM team_memberships tm 
INNER JOIN players p on p.id = tm.player_id
WHERE player_id In (1,2,3)
GROUP BY team_id


 - postgres requires the un-agreggated cols to be in the group by clause, yet when you do both row are returned, whereas in mysql only one is returned (given two players on the same team).

Comment: eh, looks like 'DISTINCT ON' is an option I didn't know about with postgres.